# Get rid of ClassCastException in different class loaders

Tags: java, websphere, ehcache

I have got my own JAR () running via separated class loaders and one JAR (**EhCache**) loaded by shared class loader. So I can access to different cache instances via singleton `CacheManager`.

How can I cast the same classes from my own JAR among separated class loaders?

When I'm trying to invoke my own method I have got **ClassCastException** like class `a.A`  is not a type of `a.A`.

PS: Can custom class loader or java reflection helps me?

Comment: Are you storing your classes in the cache? If so, as an object, or as a serializable stream (assuming that your classes implement Serializable) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to be able to share instances between the 2 classloaders, one option is to implement a shared interface.  this shared interface would have to be available from the shared classloader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. As far as I know, if you load the same class using two different class loaders, the two classes are treated as if they were totally unrelated.